# set up SendGrid on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, actionmailer, sendgrid

I'm using sendgrid and action mailer to send email from my rails app which is deployed on Heroku. My emails are being delivered but I'm not seeing any email activity in Sendgrid. The open tracking app is enabled.

I'm wondering if I've set up the app properly? I'm using the sendgrid-ruby gem and I've set

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options   = { host: ENV["DOMAIN"] }
```

and

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
:address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
:port           => '587',
:authentication => :plain,
:user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
:password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
:domain         => 'heroku.com',
:enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Can you confirm that when you login to your SendGrid dashboard and click on Email Activity (at the top in the nav) that you don't see anything?

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

SendGrid was experiencing issues with their Email Activity yesterday (https://support.sendgrid.com/hc/en-us/articles/205074437-16-Mar-Email-Activity-Unavailable-)

I would contact their support team (support@sendgrid.com) and have them take a look.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've sent emails over the past few weeks, none of which have been logged, so its not just yesterday that is an issue. I have contacted them to see if they can help though.